# How to run adb command in android,I run sendevent is fail

Tags: android

When I run the command in cmd one by one it is ok, 
like this:

[image]

but when I used command in my android code,run in my phone is fail...
look at my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sendKeyCode();
}

private void sendKeyCode(){
    try{

        //1
        String one = "sendevent /dev/input/event2 0001 0114 00000001";
        //2
        String two = "sendevent /dev/input/event2 0000 0000 00000000";

        //2.5
        String delay = "timeout 3";

        //3
        String three = "sendevent /dev/input/event2 0001 0114 00000000";

        //4
        String four = "sendevent /dev/input/event2 0000 0000 00000000";

        String all = one+";"+two+";"+three+";"+four;

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(all);


    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("tpnet","fail to run adb command");
    }
}

}
```

help me please

Comment: is no Exception and no success

Comment: Have you tried running a single command from code instead of all of them?

Comment: @Jaymes Bearden   yes, I tried,
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec(one);
runtime.exec(two);
runtime.exec(three);
runtime.exec(four);

and it doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run adb from terminal in Android Studio and if that doesn't work please check your **sdk folder and check platform-tools** in it.And check there are any adb in it.No then download it.

Comment: yes,I tried this command in my android studio terminal,  when i run this command on by on is ok,,,,I don't know why i android code is doesn't work

Comment: log is no error， the phone no action，，，Nothing at all，，，